How to download a CSV file via Excel macro plus choose the type of the file
I have a working macro, I just download an excel from a website, then I can use it.
I need a similar file but the download icon doesn't have an own 'path' and I need to choose the format type. Can I solve with the below macro, or it's more complicated. Can you help?
https://data.ecb.europa.eu/data/datasets/FM/FM.M.U2.EUR.RT.MM.EURIBOR3MD_.HSTA
Option Explicit


Sub first()
   
Dim myURL As String, sFilename As String
    myURL = "https://www.mnb.hu/letoltes/bubor2.xls"
    
    sFilename = "****\" & "file.xls"
   
    Dim WinHttpReq As Object, oStream As Object
    Set WinHttpReq = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
    WinHttpReq.Open "GET", myURL, False ', "username", "password"
    WinHttpReq.Send
   
    myURL = WinHttpReq.ResponseBody
    If WinHttpReq.Status = 200 Then
        Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        oStream.Open
        oStream.Type = 1
        oStream.Write WinHttpReq.ResponseBody
        oStream.SaveToFile sFilename, 2  ' 1 = no overwrite, 2 = overwrite
        oStream.Close
    End If
End Sub


What happens when you run the macro?

"Problems During Load"
The file saves the website to excel

Run this code and see if the data is what you are looking for;
Sub Test()
    Dim objHTTP As Object
    Dim strJSON As String
    Dim URL As String, r As Integer, c As Integer
    Dim regExp As Object, RetVal As Object
    Dim arrPattern(1 To 18) As Variant, xPattern As Variant, objList As ListObject
    
    Range("A1:R" & Rows.Count) = ""
    Range("A1:R1").Font.Bold = True
    
    Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    URL = "https://data.ecb.europa.eu/data-detail-api/FM.M.U2.EUR.RT.MM.EURIBOR3MD_.HSTA"

    objHTTP.Open "GET", URL, False
    objHTTP.send
       
    Range("A1:R1") = Array("OBS", "SERIES", "OBS_VALUE_ENTITY", "UNIT", "PERIOD_ID", "OBS_POINT", "OBS_COM", "TREND_INDICATOR", _
                           "PERIOD_NAME", "LEGEND", "OBS_STATUS", "OBS_VALUE_AS_IS", "PERIOD", "FREQUENCY", "OBS_CONF", _
                           "PERIOD_DATA_COMP", "VALID_FROM", "OBS_PRE_BREAK")
       
    If objHTTP.Status = 200 Then
        strJSON = objHTTP.responseText
            
        arrPattern(1) = """OBS"":""(.+?)"",""SERIES"":"
        arrPattern(2) = """SERIES"":""(.+?)"",""OBS_VALUE_ENTITY"":"
        arrPattern(3) = """OBS_VALUE_ENTITY"":""(.+?)"",""UNIT"":"
        arrPattern(4) = """UNIT"":""(.+?)"",""PERIOD_ID"":"
        arrPattern(5) = """PERIOD_ID"":""(.+?)"",""OBS_POINT"":"
        arrPattern(6) = """OBS_POINT"":""(.+?)"",""OBS_COM"":"
        arrPattern(7) = """OBS_COM"":""(.+?)"",""TREND_INDICATOR"":"
        arrPattern(8) = """TREND_INDICATOR"":""(.+?)"",""PERIOD_NAME"":"
        arrPattern(9) = """PERIOD_NAME"":""(.+?)"",""LEGEND"":"
        arrPattern(10) = """LEGEND"":""(.+?)"",""OBS_STATUS"":"
        arrPattern(11) = """OBS_STATUS"":""(.+?)"",""OBS_VALUE_AS_IS"":"
        arrPattern(12) = """OBS_VALUE_AS_IS"":""(.+?)"",""PERIOD"":"
        arrPattern(13) = """PERIOD"":""(.+?)"",""FREQUENCY"":"
        arrPattern(14) = """FREQUENCY"":""(.+?)"",""OBS_CONF"":"
        arrPattern(15) = """OBS_CONF"":""(.+?)"",""PERIOD_DATA_COMP"":"
        arrPattern(16) = """PERIOD_DATA_COMP"":""(.+?)"",""VALID_FROM"":"
        arrPattern(17) = """VALID_FROM"":""(.+?)"",""OBS_PRE_BREAK"":"
        arrPattern(18) = """OBS_PRE_BREAK"":""(.+?)""}"
        
        Set regExp = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    
        regExp.ignorecase = True
        regExp.Global = True
    
        For Each xPattern In arrPattern
            regExp.Pattern = xPattern
            r = 1
            c = c + 1
            If regExp.Test(strJSON) Then
                For Each RetVal In regExp.Execute(strJSON)
                    r = r + 1
                    Cells(r, c) = RetVal.Submatches(0)
                Next
            End If
        Next
        
        Set objList = ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
        
        With objList
            .ShowTotals = False
            .Name = "List_ECB"
            .Range.Columns.AutoFit
        End With
                
        
        MsgBox "Done...!", vbInformation
    Else
        MsgBox "URL problem...."
    End If
    
    Set regExp = Nothing
    Set objHTTP = Nothing
End Sub


great, thanks your effort.
